# facebook no logra leer metas desde laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook

si creo un documento html en la raiz publica "test.html"

```html
<HTML>  
<HEAD>  
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>
 <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
 <!-- Open Graph data -->
 <meta property="og:title" content="Perro labrador salva a un venado de morir ahogado (Video)" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://perritosperdidos.org/test.html" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/1500326913098.jpg" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="El ciervo se está recuperando de algunas garrapatas y una lesión ocular." />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="perritosperdidos.org" />
 <meta property="article:published_time" content="2013-09-17T05:59:00+01:00" />
 <meta property="article:modified_time" content="2013-09-16T19:08:47+01:00" />
 <meta property="article:section" content="Sección de la web" />
 <meta property="article:tag" content="perros" />
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1592837927687015" /> 
 <TITLE>TITULO DE PAGINA</TITLE>  
</HEAD>  
<BODY>  
 <!-- Aqui va todo lo chachi -->  
 <H1>Perro labrador salva a un venado de morir ahogado (Video)</H1>  
 <P><IMG SRC="http://perritosperdidos.org/noticias/1500326913098.jpg" ALIGN="MIDDLE" ALT="EL Gato Felix">
 </p>
 <H3> El ciervo se está recuperando de algunas garrapatas y una lesión ocular. </H3>
</BODY>  
</HTML>
```

y al ejecutar la prueba de facebook
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.perritosperdidos.org%2Ftest.html

me muestra sin problemas.
pero si creo el mismo codigo en un

```
test.blade.php
```

cambiando solamente por

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://perritosperdidos.org/test" />
```

y creo la ruta

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

y al ejecutar la prueba en https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.perritosperdidos.org%2Ftest

```
Could Not Connect To Server
Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.
```

y me pasa con todas las paginas que utilizo con blade, facebook no las puede leer :( tengo que hacer alguna modificación o alguien que este teniendo un problema similar?

Comment: El código de respuesta es un 502, lo cual significa que es un error del servidor donde está el sitio web, tal vez tienen alguna especie de protección que no permita a Facebook (y a otros sitios) leer páginas que usen PHP, no sé.

Comment: cuando utilizo a https://prerender.io , puedo compartir los metas sin problemas pero como versión gratuita solo puedo 250 enlaces. la verdad desconozco por que no puede ingresar ya que si fuera por causas de javascripts le creo. pero como se ve es un archivo plano y simple :(